# Missing $ symbol when passing via env variable

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

Container

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine
COPY test.py .
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "test.py" ]
```

test.py

```py
import os
import time

print(os.environ)
time.sleep(30)
```

Example pod

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: test:0.1
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    env:
      - name: TEST
        value: 1$2$$3$$$4$$$$
      - name: TEST2
        value: '1$2$$3$$$4$$$$'
      - name: TEST3
        value: '"1$2$$3$$$4$$$$"'
```

k8s v1.23 prod and v1.25 both reproduce this issue

Output

```py
environ({..., 'TEST': '1$2$3$$4$$', 'TEST2': '1$2$3$$4$$', 'TEST3': '"1$2$3$$4$$"', ... }
```

But i expect all of them be `'1$2$$3$$$4$$$$'`

Tried different type of quotes - didn't work out

Worked "1\\$2\\$\\$3\\$\\$\\$4\\$\\$\\$\\$" nothing had gone, I've got the same string (with all ”\\$”), but adding and removing '\\' doesn't look right

Comment: Please fix the explanation on what WORKED and what DID NOT at the very end of your Q. Also add what is your expected output, or goal, and what did you try in order to fix it. So far n your Q there is no specific Error, not proof on how you attempted to fix your issue [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to be a k8s [feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#envvar-v1-core). It reduce `$$` to `$` while pass env varables to containers